# My old 1.0 bot still answering in skype

Tags: botframework

I've migrated my bot to Bot Framework 3.0 and it's answering correctly in the emulator and Facebook but in Skype the previous 1.0 version is still answering. I've unregistered and re-registered Skype channel but can't get the new one answering

Any ideas?

Comment: What's your botId?

Comment: 017ed891-e84b-47d6-960c-10843e72458d I managed to get the new version answering, but there're still issues with updating the Skype/Messenger channels.